# Given vectors u and v what is the orthogonal projection of v along u?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors :
$$u = (2, 0, 2),\ \ \ \ \ v = (3, -4, -10).$$

I'm asked to find the orthogonal projection $v$ along $u$.

I found the projection of $V$ onto $U$ which was $(-14/4, 0, -14/4)$.

I have no idea of that is the right answer though, my teacher did not really teach what orthogonal projection was. He just taught basic projection of finding the distance of a point from a plane. which is the projection of a line onto a planes normal vector. Is this the same? If it is, then I believe teh answer is e?

Possible solutions are

- a $(7/2, 0, 7/2)$
- b $(11/2, 0, 11/2)$
- c $(7, 0, 7)$
- d $(-7, 0, -7)$
- e $(-7/2, 0, -7/2)$
- f $(-11/2, 0, -11/2)$

Comment: You're right. Just note that $14/4=7/2.$

Answer (score 0):

The projection of $v$ along $u$ is
$$
\frac{v\cdot u}{u\cdot u}\,u=\frac{6-20}{8}\,(2,0,2)=-\frac74\,(2,0,2)=\left(-\frac72,0,-\frac72\right).
$$

Comment: Okay, thank you! glad I understood it correctly!

Comment: Glad I could help.